# Issue with String initializer in Swift when using format parameter

Tags: ios, swift, initializer

I'm getting an error for this line of Swift code in my XCode playground:

`print(String(format: "%.2f", 3.345))`

The error reads

> No exact matches in call to initializer

I believe this means that I haven't used the right parameter names/order to call the initializer. However, when running this line of code while working on an iOS app or even in the online Swift playground http://online.swiftplayground.run/, the line runs without any issues.

When running it in the XCode playground or on my terminal through the Swift REPL however, it throws an error.

Why is this the case?

Comment: did you import Foundation?

Comment: Ah okay I just thought it was an inbuilt function that didn't require any imports. Thanks!

Comment: I made it an answer for other people searching the web.

Comment: Also I'm guessing you're fairly new to the Xcode environment. If you ever get a weird error like that, you can start by searching the Type you are using. Unfortunately the docs aren't always straight forward either, but it might give a hint as to what you're missing. For instance String has framework listed as "Swift Standard Library",  but at least if you scroll way.. down you can see you were right in the call. What language are you coming from?

Comment: Yeah I come from a web development background and I'm really new to iOS development and Swift. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Starting in Xcode beta 13 you can say e.g. `3.345.formatted(.number.precision(.fractionLength(2)))` instead, but you still need to import Foundation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Foundation has to be imported before using String.
String is a Foundation type in swift.

I was corrected by Matt below in the comments.
String is built into swift and String(format: is in foundation.
I guess that's why the docs didn't show it as such.
Thank you for the correction.

Comment: This is not true at all. String is built in to Swift. What's not built in is the `String(format:)` initializer.

Comment: @matt I'm curious is the init coming from Objective-c and how could I find that in the docs?

Comment: It's coming from Foundation. :)